# Is there a non-awful free word processor for Windows?

Tags: windows, gratis, word-processor

I've really tried to use LibreOffice (and previously the near-identical Open Office). It's sadly garbage. Two of the main annoyances/show-stoppers are:

1. It has no "dark theme", so it kills my eyes. Even if you go out of your way to follow the instructions online to "hack your own" fake dark theme, it just looks absolutely awful. It cannot be made to look decent due to the way it's designed.
2. It does not remember where I left off in the document, so every day, I am forced to manually locate where I stopped the last day in my long document. Its "bookmark" features are inane as well, so they don't remedy the situation even a little.

I'm almost desperate enough at this point to make my own word processor, for my own use. But that seems completely insane, given that the year is 2022 and *word processing* is almost literally the first application that PCs had, and were stable in the early 1980s... Although you had to pay dearly for them, admittedly.

Also, even if I wanted to pay money, they are all about "subscriptions" and "accounts" these days, which prevent me from a philosophical standpoint to use them even if money were not a problem to me. (But it is.)

Comment: Do you require a full-fat graphical word processor, or a text-typing programme ?

Comment: Power up ye *olde* computer, toss in the EasyWriter floppy disk and enjoy a high quality word processor! On the monochrome screen, green on black (or amber on black... your choice!) will automatically give you the dark mode without any hassle.  **Pro tip:** the stick-on write protect tabs for floppy disks also work great to hold Polaroids to the ice box so you can enjoy looking at them while you wait for your Kronenbourg to slowly chill!

Comment: TeXnicCenter :-), ok maybe not exactly what you're looking for, not sure it remembers where you left off.

Comment: I suppose swapping to Mac is out of the question?? Mac has two free word processors - a light one called TextEdit & a full-blown Office equivalent, Pages. Both respect dark mode, both will remember exactly where you left off, even through a reboot. [All Apple apps now return to where they were after reboot, no user intervention required. You don't even need to save the document to do this.]

Comment: Well, if you do get some money, _ye olde_ Microsoft Office is also available as a one-time purchase for about 150€, no subscriptions attached. You'll have to look hard for it though, they don't advertise it much. And it will only get so many updates, but frankly I think it's stable enough that's not a very important point anymore. And it'll be yours for life.

Comment: @Vilx - for not much more than that you could have a second-hand Mac, new enough to still run the current OS… and a free-for-life word processor on it.

Comment: Would an online web-based one be fine? For example, the online web-based version of Word [is free](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/free-office-online-for-the-web), so something like that might work.

Comment: Have you evaluated WPS Office? I found it much better than LibreOffice, but not as good as MS Office. I don't know about restoring last position (I hate that option personally) however. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WPS_Office

Comment: You'd write your own word processor, but you wouldn't contribute to LibreOffice?

Comment: @Tetsujin - True. To be honest, you might even find a used laptop with Windows and Office on it too.

Comment: What do you use the word processor for?

Comment: @Vilx- - but it wouldn't be current & it wouldn't be yours. MS prefers people to rent Office as well, these days - constantly paying for it, like Adobe.

Comment: Dont forget, you don't need to write your own, just fork Libreoffice. Also, Libreoffice can remember where you last edited, I tested the instructions in the following article and they worked for me (although I am using Linux). Libreoffice can be themed in many ways, but on Windows it may involve messing with gtk settings...

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-make-libreoffice-writer-remember-your-last-cursor-position/#:~:text=Open%20any%20LibreOffice%20document%20and,name%20and%20your%20last%20name.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try [this advice](https://itsfoss.com/libreoffice-dark-mode/)?

Comment: After 20 years of using Word, I began to no longer dread scientific writing once I discovered emacs, which is a joy for document processing.

Comment: @vilx for the life ***of your installation***.  They only plan to run the authentication servers for about 7 years, and after that, you will not be able to reinstall it.  They already did that to me on Office 2011, and Office 2022 does not support 10.13 which effectively bricks any 2011 Macs that are otherwise perfectly usable.

Comment: @Tetsujin You mentioned the possibility of buying a second-hand Mac that has 2 free word processors, for less than 150€.  I'm interested.  What is the most powerful second-hand Mac commonly sold for under 150€ that has 2 free word processors?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket - I just searched eBay 'buy it now' listings for MacBook Pro 2015 [which is the oldest that can run Monterey] & they were coming in from just under £200. TextEdit comes pre-loaded with a new OS, Pages, Numbers & Keynote are available free on the App Store.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - Wait, what? I cannot currently activate Office 2011 anymore even if all my papers are in order? Surely they at least retain the option to activate via phone or something? 

Comment: @Vilx - no, phone support ended 2017, along with all other support for 2011. I've successfully moved it from Mac to Mac for a decade without it triggering a re-authorise [but the last move was just before support ended, I haven't tested it since.] Also, 2011 won't run on Catalina or newer, so you'd also be running it on a Mac that's out of support too, Mojave went EOL with the release of Monterey.

Comment: I do believe office 2021 is the current non subscription licence version, but it may be the last

Comment: That's always been a bugbear for me - MS's licensing policy. You buy software for *that computer* not for **you**. There is a method to faff with changing licenses, but  it does mean if you own 2 computers, you only have one that works at any given time. Software like Pages, [aside from it being free anyway, this also applies to actual cost-purchases] is owned by **you** meaning you can use it on any computers you own, for life.

Comment: there isn't, write your own!! and share!

Comment: @Tetsujin - The very idea of copyright is that you DON'T own the software you use (or music, or movies, or books, or whatever). Any of it. Even the one where you pay once. Even the free one. They're all **licenced** to you and the actual owner can at any time come to you and say "nope, I forbid you to use **MY** thing". And whatever you have or have not paid them doesn't mean a thing.

Comment: @Vilx- that could be said of anything. I wasn't complaining about some capricious removal of 'right to use' I was complaining at long-established policy. One computer vs one owner [or actually up to 5 owners for the same price if you set up Family Sharing]. [Actually, your definition of copyright is a bit wrong, but that's not something I'm going to argue in here. It's close enough].

Comment: @Tetsujin - Ahh, I got it now. Well... yes. I agree with you, it's annoying and stupid. And I'm 99% sure that it was done so because it was the only thing that could be enforced programmatically. But then... I don't see this any more or less stupid than all the other limitations that copyright (and, more generally, "intellectual property") places on people.

Comment: @Vilx for reference, Adobe did the exact same with CS2 - took down the authentication servers (but by accident) - but *their* response was to patch it to remove the auth code requirements. Anyone with sufficiently vintage hardware can run CS2. Obviously this did not explode sales of PowerMacs or end sales of CC.

Comment: A word processor like LIbre Office has a vast number of features and you call it "awful" because you don't like the theme and the bookmarking? I'm sure that will prompt all those people who contributed countless hours to this free, open-source project to just fall all over themselves to meet your needs.  As commented already, why not contribute to the project, perhaps by writing a dark theme you don't consider "awful"?

Comment: Actually LibreOffice does support theming on Linux. The problem is that Windows UI doesn't support theming. Also global dark theme might actually work on Win11 now.

Comment: It seems quite derogatory and vague to call known word processors "awful" or "garbage". I would suggest an edit to put the actual show-stoppers listed in the title, but I'm not sure if the existing answers meet those requirements. Although I can't recall any word processor remembering where I left off after I closed it (and I can't recall any forgetting while I keep it open). And if looking at a screen is hurting your eyes, I would suggest changing the colour range of your screen, making sure you have proper lighting in your room, getting glasses and/or taking regular breaks above dark mode.

Comment: Your rant here is quite disrespectful.  https://www.libreoffice.org/about-us/who-are-we/   And why would you think about writing your word processor, when  you could just patch those few issues in LibreOffice Writer? That's orders of magnitude less work, even if a lot of work nevertheless.

Comment: @UliceMidler: Please take back the phrase "garbage". It's quite offensive to say that about the result of the hard work of thousands of volunteers over many years. Say it's "inadequate", "unsatisfactory", say that you "hate it" - but you just mentioned two features you're missing. That does not justify a factual claim of it being "garbage".

Comment: Could you not use control + f to find the passage in the document you need? It has a built in search function

Comment: @Tetsujin You can still activate Windows 2003 by phone (yes - I do it at work every few months, as we are a testing team and regularly reinstall our systems) and you cannot activate Office 2011 anymore? This makes no sense. Also, I don't know about later versions, but we still use Office 2007 at work and when I installed it, it didn't require any activation. You had just to enter the license key.

Comment: I don't know if Windows has this feature (it may be available in accessibility options), but on Linux you can easily (usually with a single keypress) switch either the entire screen, or the currently active window, to negative, which gives you something like "dark mode" instantly in any application.

Comment: You can use Adobe Acrobat.

Answer (score 20):

You are not writing what you are using your word processor **for**.

For my needs, I have found that Atom (or any other modern text editor) and [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) gets me almost everything I need, and I can easily preview it and export it to PDF. I save immense amounts of time not messing with layout in a word processor that can't decide if it wants to be a text editor or a DTP tool.

When I need something for print, I use InDesign (which isn't free, of course). There is [Scribus](https://www.scribus.net/) as a free alternative but I've never worked with it.

My previous solution was LyX, which is a WYSIWYG front-end for LaTeX, which someone else already recommended.

Comment: Note that InDesign and Sublime are not free. https://www.sublimehq.com/store/text Atom is both free and open-source.

Comment: @Gantendo you're right. I've updated the text. It's not important which text editor you use, most modern text editors have syntax highlighting for Markdown.

Comment: +1 for Markdown. [Typora](https://typora.io/) is an excellent markdown editor. It used to be free while in beta, but apparently isn't anymore :( . Markdown is usually more than enough for what I need, the learning curve is almost non-existent. To convert to PDF, I use [jupyter notebook](https://jupyter.org/), [mkdocs](https://mkdocs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or Typora. EDIT: https://marktext.app/ could be an open-source alternative to Typora. I've never used it.

Comment: @EricDuminil pandoc is also an excellent converter, and can export markdown as docx and other formats you might need. The Atom module "markdown preview enhanced" also has various exporters included, and there's another "markdown to PDF" module. So there are plenty of options.

Comment: @Tom thanks for the info. Pandoc looks really powerful. I've never used it directly, but I think it can be called under the hood by Jupiter notebook. The PDF from Jupiter is compiled with LaTeX, I don't know if pandoc is involved when LaTeX is installed.

Answer (score 19):

You could just use Google Docs.

I've found that for 90% of features and 95% of people it has all the functionality that you'd find in Microsoft Office. (Obviously estimated numbers, but based on dealing with lots of semi-technical people at a software company.)

You can use them offline following [this](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) guide.

[This](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-docs-dark-mode/lgjhepbpjcmfmjlpkkdjlbgomamkgonb?hl=en) Chrome extension seems to do a good job of dark mode.

EDIT 1: Good point from Basile Starynkevitch about the files being stored outside of your control.

I would suggest using [Drive for Desktop](https://www.google.com/intl/en-GB/drive/download/) to sync the files you want to your desktop. Then as an additional precaution you could have Windows or 3rd party software backup this folder as well.

EDIT 2: A frustration I used to have was having to go into Google Drive to create new documents but now Google has bought the ".new" domain and have enabled "[docs.new](http://docs.new)", "[sheets.new](http://sheets.new)", "[presentation.new](http://presentation.new)"("[slides.new](http://slides.new)" is the shorter version) etc. as shortcuts to create new documents.

Comment: The disadvantage of Google Docs is that the documentation is hosted outside of your (or your employer's) control.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the documentation like the "how to use" info? Or do you mean your own documents? "How to use" = many sources available.  I would expect manufacturers to produce only skeletal docs and leave social media to do the real educating.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica It's not my recommendation (I try to stay far away from Google and their "you are the product" services), but I'm guessing the OP meant "your documents".

Comment: @Rock I hear you, but if you want to avoid "being the product" that crosses off much of the Internet, including StackExchange.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yep.   My use of a chunk of the Internet is now zero, and I limit my use of StackExchange.  I actually have large swaths of Google, Facebook, & Microsoft IP ranges blocked at a low level.  That said, a good part of the non-FAANG+MS internet is truly free.

Comment: I mean that with Google Docs your own documents (the text you are writing) are stored on Google servers. Perhaps they contain confidential information that you don't want Google to access....

Comment: "Then as an additional precaution you could have Windows or 3rd party software backup this folder as well." — As of this writing, if you did that, you would only be backing up links to the same files. The better way to do this is to, in Drive, download the folder as a zip. This causes Drive to convert all files to Word docs for download, which does make it possible to back them up as discrete files. And they can be uploaded and converted back to Google Docs with fairly good consistency of formatting if the need arises, without ever actually owning Word.

Answer (score 16):

Consider learning, then using [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX). See https://www.latex-project.org/

It is an open source software and free of cost.

### You need to read books about LaTeX before using it.

Budget a week of work, and buy some books about LaTeX.

With [HeVeA](http://hevea.inria.fr/) (also open source) you can use LaTeX to generate both documents (printable PDF files) and web pages.

If you need a more or less WYSIWYG graphical interface to LaTeX, consider using [LyX](https://www.lyx.org/) (also open source).

All the books I have about LaTeX have been written with it. The typography is excellent. And you can embed drawings (e.g. made with [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org)), mathematical or chemical formulaes, and with [MusixTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MusiXTeX) extensions musical scores.

And LaTeX can be used on Windows, on Linux, on MacOSX. You probably want to use [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) and some version control system, like [git](https://git-scm.com/), with it. All of LaTeX, `emacs`, and `git` are open source.

A lot of computer science conferences accept, or even *require*, submission in LaTeX.

A lot of books published by OReilly (about computers, programming, ...) are written with LaTeX.

Most PhD dissertations in computer science, math, or physics are written in LaTeX.

---

> It does not remember where I left off in the document, so every day, I am forced to manually locate where I stopped the last day in my long document.

My old trick for that is (in some *draft* document) to add some *temporary text* with weird punctuation or string. For example: `@*@*@TO BE COMPLETED` (sometimes I highlight it in red). Then you need to search the `@*@*@` string. This trick does not require any capability of your word processor or document formater, beyond searching for some weird punctuation (which is your *conventional* one, choozen to be unlikely to appear in the definitive text). If you forgot your convention, put a post-it on your desk (or send you some email about what is remaining to be written / corrected / improved).

---

> I'm almost desperate enough at this point to **make my own word processor**, for my own use.

### This is an excellent idea.

I hope your word processor would be **open source**. Have you started to work on it? Maybe you might contact Jeff Kingston (in Australia) with his [Nonpareil project](http://jeffreykingston.id.au/nonpareil/).

---

NB. Another [text formatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typesetting) is [Lout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lout_(software)). Also open source, also running on Linux, Windows, MacOSX.

PS. My pet open source project is [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/). Feel free to email me about it.

Comment: @ZOMVID-21: what are the other functions that LaTeX+GNU emacs don't provide?

Comment: WYSIWYG editing

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury: That should be told in the question.

Comment: I disagree that you need to read about LaTeX before using. If you have never used another scripting language, then yes maybe. But otherwise it's probably fine to just download a template and then google problems as and when you meet them. OP is considering writing a word processor, they likely have scripted before, they can just jump straight in.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury LaTeX can be WYSISYG, it's an odd thing to want, but it is available. http://www.bakoma-tex.com/menu/about.php

Comment: I don't think that the "write my own" line was meant literally...

Comment: A variant on this idea is to use LyX, which works out most of the LaTeX for you, allowing you to use a WYSIWYM interface (not quite the same as the WYSIWYG one may expect of Word, but a lot friendlier to such expectations than LaTeX alone). I use it for a lot, including my theses & even novels.

Comment: @J.G.: I mentioned LyX (in  my answer) before your comment. In [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) we use LaTeX.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice. In that case, just consider my contribution across these two comments to be a "seconded" from my own experience.

Comment: For a more IDE-like experience with LaTeX instead of WYSIWYM that LyX provides, one can try [TexStudio](https://www.texstudio.org/), which is also free & opensource. One feature I like there is that it lets one have the preview in the same IDE window, which appears after pressing the "build and view" shortcut, and can also navigate to the required part of the source by right-clicking the preview and choosing *Go to Source*.

Comment: A cloud-based alternative to TexStudio is Overleaf. It's very easy to get started on and can be a good place to learn LaTeX and sample the workflow before going through the effort to get everything set up locally.

Comment: @Tom I used to use TeXstudio and was pretty happy with it.  I now use MS VS Code with the LaTeX Workshop extension and I'm very pleased with it.  You could load one of the IEEE bare conference or journal LaTeX documents from the IEEEtran package and play around with it to see how the editor and LaTeX works.

Comment: And if one doesn't like latex all that much one can still write in markdown (with the occasional inline latex where needed) and convert it to latex using Pandoc

Comment: Depending on OP's needs, there is no need to spend weeks on reading documentation. I would recommend to start with [A (Not So) Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english), subtitle says "Or LATEX 2ε in 139 minutes"

Comment: > *I hope your word processor would be open source.*   Me too! Then I will post a rant here about how it is unusable garbage.

Answer (score 14):

LibreOffice definitely has a dark mode, as well as support for dark themes. See [here](https://itsfoss.com/libreoffice-dark-mode/) for the details. Example screenshots:

[image]

[image]

You can get the [Dracula theme for LibreOffice](https://draculatheme.com/libreoffice) (popular as a dark mode theme in many apps), and I'm sure there are some others floating around as well.

As for remembering your position in a file - why not:

1. Find this feature request at bugs.freedesktop.org
2. If it doesn't get promptly implemented (very likely) - consider  implementing it yourself

?

That's much easier than trying to write your own word processor.

Comment: Also, if you are on Linux (I don't know if Windows has such feature - it may be available in accessibility options) you can easily (usually with a single keypress) switch either the entire screen, or the currently active window, to negative, which gives you something like "dark mode".

Comment: BTW, LibreOffice has the reputation of a very kind developer community. If you want to contribute to coding it, you *will* get gentle help.

Answer (score 12):

There is SoftMaker [FreeOffice](https://www.freeoffice.com/en).

This has both free and paid-for versions.  The appearance and use are much closer to MS Office than the Free / Libre Office alternatives.

To run the free version sensibly, you will have to turn off an advertising panel that it puts up by default but, once done, it doesn't come back.

You will have to register for a key.  You will get the occasional "Please upgrade" email on the address you use for this.

They are the only niggles I can think of.

SoftMaker FreeOffice is cross-platform: It is available for Linux, macOS, and Windows.

Comment: What is the approx speed to load Free Office these days (relative to MS Office / LibreOffice / OpenOffice)?  When I tried it a few years ago, it loaded much faster than the applications in MS Office, LibreOffice, and OpenOffice.

Comment: Difficult to give a definitive answer but FreeOffice is faster than LibreOffice on my laptop.  I only use MS Office nowadays on another machine and that one is noticeably slower, but how much of that difference is the machine rather than the Office I couldn't say.

Comment: Thanks.  BTW, on Windows (but no longer on Linux), you can set LibreOffice to load some of its components on boot.  It's still fairly laggy, but it does help.  IIRC, OpenOffice has something similar that works on Linux and Windows.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket that's always been a kludge, and not a workable one: a decade ago I tried it with OpenOffice (on Linux IIRC), and these preloaded components tended to get swapped out due to being unused, so that once you really need to start e.g. Writer, you still hear HDD seeks and wait for the swapped-out pages to be loaded into RAM.

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks for the info.  On Windows 7, the LibreOffice preloader works well.  I generally disable all preloaders, but I have tested that particular one and it works well.  There is currently a LibreOffice bug that prevents it from loading without enabling it in both the installer *and* after a LibreOffice app in open.  But once that's done, it works as expected.  I wonder if LibreOffice removed their preloader from Linux for the reasons you mentioned.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket "It's [LibreOffice] still fairly laggy" - What do you consider "laggy"?

Comment: @MrWhite I find LibreOffice apps take a fairly long time to load and enter a stable state ready for user input.  Also, some basic operations have long (multi-second) delays before the UI responds, making one wonder if the LibreOffice application hung.  That said, LibreOffice is free, and I have only made minor contributions to it and OpenOffice, so I'm grateful for both.

Answer (score 7):

(Many answers and comments to this question ask for some more context as to the purpose and needs of the said “word processing”. Which is kind of an essential question, of course. What the original asker actually wants to *do* with the tool largely determines what kind of software they should be looking for.)

---

**Principles**

As of this writing, I did not immediately find comments from the original asker clarifying their intent and needs concerning “word processing”.

Still, my recommendation to anyone looking for a general “word-processing” tool — or rather, a *document creation toolset* — is based on two principles:

1. Look for an editor that will produce documents in a standard, widely-accepted, [structured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_document) [markup format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) which several tools can process (so not tied to a single vendor), and which is expressive enough to mark up complex prose or (technical) documents. There are basically five such formats:

   1. [DocBook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DocBook) (Used for many O’Reilly books)
   2. [DITA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_Information_Typing_Architecture) (maybe better-suited for larger, collaboratively written projects which share bits and pieces but not so much for individual, self-contained documents?)
   3. [XHTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML#XHTML5) (maybe lacks the number of finer-graded semantic and structural elements present in DocBook that are useful for actually describing a complex book-like title, but you can’t get much more universal than (X)HTML in terms of support)
   4. [reStructuredText](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText) (rst, as used for Python documentation, among other projects)
   5. [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) (more of a print layout markup format than a pure structured document format but still structured and abstract enough to suffice for this purpose (and venerable enough to deserve a mention))

   Pay attention to features in the markup language which facilitate the markup of different semantic span segments, and block elements such as chapters, sections, admonitions, quotations, excerpts of terminal output (for technical documents), author and document metadata, complex tables, pixel-based and vector images, etc.

   Conversely, keep clear of “easy” document markup formats which are ill-defined both in terms of expressiveness and standardization, such as the ever-present [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown). (The initial easiness and ad hoc-ness comes with a price which you start paying later on when you want to do anything more complex.)
2. Try to find a document editor which allows *access* to the raw markup, but does not force you to *work* in the raw markup mode — a so-called [WYSIWYM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYM) (What You See Is What You Mean) editor.

   The basic principle behind a WYSIWYM, structured document editor is that it resembles a “consumer” word processor in that editing is a breeze — you can edit the document directly in a styled preview mode — but still lets you keep tabs on what is exactly happening in the markup and structure of the document and ensures that the produced markup will never be invalid or contain superfluous auto-generated markup — much less any messy ad-hoc styling, which is a common and almost unavoidable occurrence in the “consumer” word processors even if you do not want any such styling.

   This is typically achieved in a WYSIWYM, structured document editor by it only ever producing document structure that correctly validates against a given document markup schema. In other words, the editor is “strictly validating” and, at any point, simply does not *let* you insert markup elements in the document structure that would go against the document markup schema but keeps them out of reach from you — grayed out or filtered out in the lists and menu or toolbar options where you might otherwise choose them.

   That said, a WYSIWYM structured document editor usually does not require you to work with the raw markup elements as such (or that much) but will present at least the most common ones — such as the different section/heading elements, basic paragraphs, or different types of lists or spans of emphasis — as easily-accessible toolbar buttons and keyboard shortcuts.

   I would advise keeping clear of the *purported* “WYSIWYM” editors which show you a styled document preview in one pane but only allow editing the content in another which shows you the raw markup. This kind of a “lazy man’s” implementation is somewhat counterproductive and *not* how a true WYSIWYM editor works. While it is important to have *access* to the raw markup as well, it is much easier to edit and maintain the document if you can type text directly in a styled view which does not *let* you produce invalid structure, which shows you a rendition of the document with some rudimentary styling, and which does not force you to think the document in terms of raw markup all the time.

---

[image: XMLmind XML Editor]

**Recommendation**

Given the above principles, my personal favorite for structured document creation and editing is currently a WYSIWYM editor called [XMLmind XML Editor](https://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/) (pictured above), which is “is a strictly validating, near WYSIWYG, XML editor” supporting DocBook, DITA, and XHTML markup, and “Free to use by individuals, open source projects and non-profit organizations.” I use it in the DocBook mode, specifically.

This preference for DocBook is because I find DocBook expressive enough in its semantic markup for most literary works, well-suited for self-contained documents, and a good “manuscript” or “source code” format from which conversions can be made to lesser distribution formats.

The preference for the XMLmind XML Editor is because it does not get in your way and lets you type in content “directly” while viewing it with a nice preview stylesheet, and also keeps the document structure in check (in adherence to the DocBook document schema) — so I do not have to do any manual validation, ever, or worry about the structure or markup itself being incorrect.

To fully appreciate the editor, you need to teach yourself about the Ctrl + arrow keys, Ctrl + I, Ctrl + R, Ctrl + T, Ctrl + E and other shortcuts for dealing with basic element selection and nested elements, and you need to teach yourself a bit about the DocBook format itself (what elements are available, how they are supposed to be used, and what kind of attributes they take). But once you have passed those hurdles, it otherwise feels much like a “saner Word” where things are always in order and nothing will ever happen behind your back.

It is important to learn the keyboard shortcuts for everything, though, down to choosing DocBook elements from the offered, context-sensitive list by typing in a part of their name, as it makes you much more productive than clicking the menus and dialogs with a mouse.

---

**Benefits of structured document markup**

I like the fact that in structured document markup, structure and semantics is everything, and the final styling (via style sheets) is something that you only worry about later, once you have produced the content. This is how it should be, especially in the modern world where there can be many ways to consume the content, and many different content styling requirements and distribution formats.

Working with structured, semantic markup lets you focus purely on the content and the task at hand instead of getting lost with adjusting minor styling details “in-place” — often with disastrous results, and a need to do constant readjustments when you change something in the content later on, as is common in “consumer” word processors. Unfortunately, the “consumer” word processors have, so far, only had feeble attempts to implement any structure to their workflows and seem to mix structure with unwanted inline styling all the time.

**Further considerations**

To go from a DocBook “manuscript” to a distribution format, such as PDF or EPUB, you need a document processing toolchain of some sort which will filter the document through a stylesheet and produce a transformed copy in the distribution format while generating a table of contents and other such structures. The aforementioned XMLmind XML Editor includes some such conversion tools (e.g. a conversion from DocBook to HTML format) but you could also use external toolsets, and tweak their conversion parameters and stylesheets to your liking.

If you find the LaTeX route better-suited for your purposes, you will probably want to look at a WYSIWYM editor for LaTeX called [LyX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LyX).

For reStructuredText, there’s the [Sphinx document processor](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/), which probably warrants a honorable mention, but no compatible free WYSIWYM editor (that I know of)... so you’re pretty much restricted to a standard programmer’s text editor when editing the content. And while reStructuredText does many things better and in a more standardized way than Markdown (except for the heading markup, which is very weird and icky in rst), it is still an overgrown README format trying hard to be something like XML without tags, which is a somewhat doomed battle. Beyond very basic formatting, you need to introduce some kind of “tags” and markup with complex syntactical rules anyway and editing your “simple text file with complex rules” will pretty quickly get just as involved as when using actual XML markup to hold the document structure — only with a less explicit syntax and less standardized tools to deal with it.

Comment: I've done all my technical writing this way for years, though the editor I use is Oxygen rather than XMLMind. I only use a word processor for writing short letters (increasingly rare!) and for that, OpenOffice is fine.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Yes, as far as I know, Oxygen XML Editor is fairly similar to XMLmind XML Editor in its operating principle — maybe even more polished — but I do not have much experience on it (I think I tried a trial version many years ago, but that’s about it.) I did not mention it in the answer since unlike XMLmind, they do not seem to have a free version of any kind available for download, only time-limited trials.

Answer (score 5):

> Also, even if I wanted to pay money, they are all about "subscriptions" and "accounts" these days, which prevent me from a philosophical standpoint...

Huh?

Buy the non-subscription version and move on with your life.

Microsoft - [Office Home & Student 2021 - One-time purchase for 1 PC or Mac](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/p/office-home-student-2021/cfq7ttc0h8n8?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab)

Amazon - [Office Home & Student 2021 - One-time purchase for 1 PC or Mac](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09H7GPR1G)

---

Wanna save a buck? Try [Kinguin](https://www.kinguin.net/listing?active=0&hideUnavailable=0&phrase=office&page=0&size=25&sort=bestseller.total,DESC)

Comment: That Kinguin site looks shady. Cheap keys like that usually come with issues. They might not necessarily be outright scams (though some probably are), but they might be already used or they could be sold to multiple people. All of which will result in problems when you try to activate your Office online.

Comment: @Vilx- So go ahead and use the other two URLs I provided. As someone with well over 30 Kinguin purchases I've only recently had a problem with an invalid Windows 11 key. I received a new key within 24 hours with no hassle. 32 bucks for an Office key isn't a terribly expensive lesson to experience.

Comment: True, true. Still, I think that it's worth to put out a disclaimer so that people know what they are risking with.

Comment: Where do you think they get those keys so cheap? Microsoft doesn't sell them like that. What you have are either volume licence keys (which are meant for large companies and not supposed to be resold), or MSDN keys. Either way, they're not legal (well, if anyone ever checks that is), and in some cases they can stop working. I'm not saying "don't do it", just - "there is _some_ risk of losing your money attached to it, and it is greater than buying for the official price".

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Here, I second that it is shady. Microsoft doesn't sell those keys for that cheap. They certainly aren't paying the difference themselves because they're feeling nice, so chances are they are doing something shady, like volume licenses, selling to multiple people, or other things that could cause issues for the buyer later if the key is illegitimate, which it easily could be. They need some way to get the difference between the Microsoft price and their price, and that way is probobly shady.

Comment: Microsoft Office Home & Student is limited exclusively to non-commercial use, that means you cannot use it in connection with any activity that you participate in primarily for financial gain.

Comment: Kinguin is only a marketplace connecting buyers to third party sellers.  Like eBay.  Therefore every transaction is a crapshoot.  Come to it, the same is true of Amazon, though some sales are by Amazon proper.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica perhaps you can go to the [Microsoft Redmond campus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Redmond_campus) so you feel corporate and safe enough? </sarcasm>

Comment: @VS I only install electrical equipment that is UL listed (or other NRTL).  Is that fanatical enough for you? :)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your tastes and goals, "Emacs" (google "emacs for Windows"...) has been my text editor on unix/linux for 30 years, and on Mac OS since 2006, when that OS started including many aspects of a *nix set-up.

Emacs (or "Aquamacs" on MacOS) is user-configurable in every conceivable manner...

With my set-up of it, it is *not* WYSIWYG at all, deliberately, because I want to see the literal characters I've entered to a file. This has been useful at times in the past when a file got slightly mangled, and I could look directly at the characters in it, rather than simply having a word-processing program declare it corrupted/unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

There is one (not yet mentioned option): [OnlyOffice](https://www.onlyoffice.com/) (as a desktop version as well as online Google Docs-like one - however, the latter one is deployed on your own infrastructure, thus keeping the docs under *your* control). The community version includes nearly all the features apart from those like paid support etc and is fully open-source (GNU AGPL v3, here are Github repositories for [the server](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/CommunityServer) and [desktop editors](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/DesktopEditors)).

It has a [dark theme](https://www.onlyoffice.com/blog/2021/06/onlyoffice-desktop-editors-v6-3-with-dark-theme-and-150-scaling/) (for both desktop and online version). The interface mimics MS Office (AFAIK the goal is to achieve maximum compatibility with it), so it is easy to understand and use for those familiar with Microsoft's product.

Of course, there are some drawbacks. For example, the desktop editors are also build with Web interfaces via Electron engine (which is famous for inefficient resource usage, so it may consume a lot of RAM and CPU time). Also (as of 2022) some advanced features like bibliography management are still missing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using simply wordPad on windows?
Simple and free.
Saves in RTF (word can open..) and can open .doc (even cannot resave in .doc).

On Mac, "Pages" is far beyond paid word, many nice features